# Neo4j Cypher Query Regular Expression using a property in a regular expression

Tags: regex, neo4j, cypher

How do you return a set of two types of nodes using the property of one, in a regular expression

ie A node (c) with the value of 'Mary Jane Smith' and a node (d) with the value of 'Mary'

I have issues if I try

Match (c:Char_Name), (d:Char) where c.value =~ '.*'+d.value+'.*' return c,d limit 10

(the c node is a fullname, the d node are made of elements of those names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit sketchy, but it works in the console.

```
MATCH (d:Char)
WITH d, "." + d.value + "." AS regex
MATCH (c:Char_Name)
WHERE c.value =~ regex
RETURN c, d
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you for the response John. I had to add stars just after the dots (regex version of nil or more than) for it to work. But the fact that it does makes me happy! Correct answer.